# Android: setListAdapter sets only last row in database

Tags: android, database, listview, adapter

as the title states I am having a little trouble linking my data from a database to a listview, the problem being that the adapter will set only the last row returned, as opposed to each row from the database table.

An example of what I am trying to achieve:

TABLE ANIMAL:
Monkey
Cat
Dog
Tiger

will show up as only Tiger on screen.

My method returning cursor from the database:

```
public Cursor retrieveAnimals(){

    return = DB.query(ANIMAL_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ANIMALNAME,
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);      
}
```

and setting the listview

```
    dbm = new MyDBManager(this);
    dbm.open();
    dbm.deleteAnimals();
    dbm.populateDB();

    // after populating, set the adapter..
    myCursor = dbm.getAllAnimals();

String[] columns = new String[] {"animal_name"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.animal};

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myCursor, columns, to);
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I have a feeling my problem lies in the cursor position, in that it is moving automatically to the last row when setting the adapter, I have been trying to find a solution to my problem but with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT: Method to populate DB

```
public long populateDB(){


    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANIMALNAME, animalName[i]);
    }

    return DB.insert(ANIMAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}
```

Comment: What does `myCursor.getCount()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `retrieveAnimals()`, the line should be `return DB.query(...)` (note the lack of an `=` between `return` and `DB.query`).

Apart from that your code looks fine. You should call `startManagingCursor` on the cursor (after calling `getAllAnimals`) to avoid memory leaks.

Edit: change your populate method to:

```
public long[] populateDB(){


    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    long[] rowIds = new long[animalName.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
        // here we are using a single ContentValues object and inserting it
        // into the DB before changing the ContentValues and inserting it again
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANIMALNAME, animalName[i]);
        rowIds[i] = DB.insert(ANIMAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    return rowIds;

}
```

Alternatively (more memory usage, but useful perhaps if you need to modify some of the records before inserting them):

```
public void populateDB(){

    ContentValues[] initialValues = new ContentValues[animalName.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
        // create a new ContentValues for each object
        initialValues[i] = new ContentValues();
        initialValues[i].put(KEY_ANIMALNAME, animalName[i]);
    }

    // now our contentvalues is filled we can insert them all
    for(int i = 0; i < animalName.length; i++){
        DB.insert(ANIMAL_TABLE, null, initialValues[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joseph, the = was left over from when I was assigning a cursor and returning it as opposed to method above, upon removal nothing has changed.

Comment: In that case, as per @Rajath's comment - what does `myCursor.getCount()` give you? If the answer is 1 then the database is only returning 1 record from the database.

Comment: getCount() returns a 1. I have edited original post with my method to populate the database, I can't seem to pick a problem with it.So my problem is basically the cursor is returning with only 1 row when there should be several.

Comment: Yes the issue is with populating the database - what you are doing is only inserting one record, you are just changing the `KEY_ANIMALNAME` value of the ContentValues lot's of times! See my edited answer for a solution, or alternatively you could make an array of `ContentValues[]` and use `bulkInsert`. For performance reasons it would be a good idea to do the inserts in a transaction of you are inserting a lot of records.

Comment: Thank you.Certainly I will not forget this step in the future you have saved my a lot of hair pulling and most importantly time!Would it be possible you could explain WHY rowIds made the difference.My understanding is insert returns "the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred ".If this action is done AFTER insertion, how does it make a difference WHEN inserting?

Comment: `rowIds` did not make the difference, you could ignore the return value from `DB.insert` if you wanted. The difference is that `DB.insert` is called every time in the `for` loop. In your first example, `DB.insert` was only called once so only one row was inserted. Also you only made one `ContentValues` object, and just changed the KEY_ANIMALNAME property of this one object lots of times, resulting in one object with the KEY_ANIMALNAME set to the value of the last row.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative method, though I would recommend the first since it uses only a single ContentValues object and so uses less memory that the second approach. With the alternative approach you could put the inserts into the same loop as the creating the ContentValues part to speed things up a little, but I left this out to illustrate that you need lots of `ContentValues` in an array, and then to insert them all.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
myCursor.moveToFirst()
```

Comment: Hi Rajath thanks for the suggestion,I have added this code right after retrieving cursor from DB, it has not made a difference.